# Cannot assign to read only property 'backgroundColor' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [headingText, setHeadingText] = useState("Hello");

  const changeColor = { backgroundColor: "" };
  function handleClick() {
    setHeadingText("Submitted");
  }
  function handleMouseOver() {
    changeColor.backgroundColor = "black";
  }
  function handleMouseOut() {
    changeColor.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{headingText}</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="What's your name?" />
      <button
        style={changeColor}
        onClick={handleClick}
        onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
        onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ERROR:Cannot assign to read only property 'backgroundColor' of object '#'**

**I was trying to create a kind of form, in which the submit button should change to black on hover and to white on getting out.Can anyone help it out.**

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code but I am not getting the error you mentioned.

> ERROR: Cannot assign to read-only property 'backgroundColor' of object '#'`

Also changing the constant `changeColor` will have no impact on the button as it will not cause the re-render. You need to use it as `state` variables.

```js
const [changeColor, setChangeColor] = useState({ backgroundColor: "" });

  function handleMouseOver() {
    setChangeColor({
      backgroundColor: "black"
    });
  }
  function handleMouseOut() {
    setChangeColor({
      backgroundColor: "white"
    });
  }
```

But this can also be achieved using `:hover` selector as follows

```
.button_submit:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

for the button

```
<button 
    className="button_submit"
    onClick={handleClick}
>
    Submit
</button>
```